# With jQuery, how do you add an element before another element without making copies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a situation where I need to add a sibling element to a jQuery object that is stored in a variable. I need the added element to be the previous sibling of that jQuery object.

The simplified version would look something like this https://jsfiddle.net/sjncgaLf/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var test = $('<div class = "test">test</div>');
  var el = $('<div class = "el">el</div>');

  //I want to add el before test (without making a copy)
  //and then append the selector (el + test) to the DOM

  el.before(test);
  $("body").append(test);
});
```

Clearly, based on the jsfiddle, this code does not achieve the desired affect. My goal is to achieve a result like this

```
<div class = "el">el</div>
<div class = "test">test</div>
```

Without copying the original elements. I've read the .before, .insertBefore, and .add documentation thoroughly, and it looks like none of those will produce exactly what I want here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I suppose need to be more clear. I'm making a calendar 1 month at a time. I need to start with a variable like $markup, and add weeks to it until I've added each day in the month. I also need to add a label to the month, like "July, 2016". So, before I append any weeks to my $markup variable, or append anything to the DOM, I want my $markup to look like this

```
<div class = "label">July 2016</div>
<div class = "CalendarWeek"></div>
```

I'll then iterate over the days of that month and add as many CalendarWeek and CalendarDay as need be.

Comment: Maybe we need more of your actual code, because appending el then appending test like this works just fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/sjncgaLf/8/

Comment: *"...result like this: EL, TEST"* even though you use `el.before(test)`... ??

Comment: What stops you from obvious solution `$("body").append(el); $("body").append(test);` ?

Comment: I added and edit to the question, I would like to create my markup for the entire calendar month stored in a variable before appending anything to the DOM if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the [jQuery - insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) method.
I have updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjncgaLf/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create elements
  var test = $('<div class = "test">test</div>');
  var el = $('<div class = "el">el</div>');
  // add the first element
  $("body").append(test);
  // insert the second element 
  el.insertBefore(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
 $("body").append(el,test);
```

the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sjncgaLf/14/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, you just need to edit your variable, not worry about appending data in order.

So for your $markup variable, if it already has data and you want to add your month label at the beginning, just use:

```
$temp = $label + $markup;
$markup = $temp;
```

To add weeks or day data to the end of your $markup variable, just use:

```
$markup = $markup + $day;
```

Once you've got the entire variable built the way you like you can use jQuery to append it where you want.

Comment: I don't think you can use the '+' operator to add 2 jQuery objects together.

Comment: It works just fine.  That's one way to concatenate strings in javascript.

Comment: on strings, not objects.

Comment: Right.  These variables, like `$markup` and `$label`  in this case, would just be strings until they're applied to a DOM object.